# When does/doesn't Bendixson's criterion apply to homoclinic orbits?

Tags: dynamical-systems

When I look at the proof for [Bendixson's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem), I don't see why this doesn't also rule out the existence of homoclinic orbits in planar dynamical systems.

Is this true and does the proof work in the exact same way?